# Visual Studio Code commits untracked files (!). How to prevent this behaviour?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, commit

So I added a file containing sensitive information to my working folder.
When I committed using VS Code, I was shocked to see that that file, maked as untracked, was being committed.

My understanding of Git is that for files to be committed they must first be tracked and staged.

Is VS Code committing everything in the folder (unless you add it to .gitignore, which is not very working-friendly (as having to add all the new files to .gitignore is a pesky task...).

I may be missing something.

Thanks for your help!

I committed changed from within VS Code expecting only those changes in tracked files that had been staged to be committed. VS Code committed everything and pushed to repo sensitive untracked info.

Comment: Git itself does require a `git add` before a `git commit`, so that the file that was untracked (i.e., not in Git's index / staging-area) is now in Git's index/staging-area, i.e., is now tracked. What VSCode does, I have no idea, but some people think it's a service (as opposed to a disservice) to auto-add files.

Comment: VSCode can be configured in many ways, but yes, it considers new files stuff that could be added. It gives you a lot of options as to what to commit when you make a commit, so pay close attention to them and pick the right one.

Comment: Now, you can make your life a lot easier by taking the time to create a good `.gitignore` file for your project, it will save you a lot of time in the future. Plus, you don't have to do it all by hand, a tool like gitignore.io (e.g., https://www.toptal.com/developers/gitignore) or gitignore templates (https://github.com/github/gitignore) can provide pre-written .gitignore contents for you based on your project's language, and then you only need to add individual additional files by hand, like your secrets file.

Comment: Thanks, probably that is the best idea.